# Versioning of input in Java API

Tags: java, spring-boot, versioning

I have a Spring Boot API which takes JSON as the input and uses the data to populate an XML which is sent to another application.

I'm currently looking at versioning for this. One approach I'm taking is to add either URI or header based versioning. I'll most likely go for the header based option by including the version in the Accept header.

I'm also looking into options for versioning the input data itself.  The input JSON has changed quite significantly recently and this has caused problems where any updates have had to be coordinated with updates to the client applications. If possible I want to include some form of versioning so API updates can be released without need to coordinate with client updates.

An example of changes include the below where the JSON structure was changed from:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "dateOfBirth": "01/01/1970",
    "occupation": "TCH",
    "contractDetails": {
        "startDate": "08/12/2022"
    }
}
```

to:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "personalDetails: {
      "dateOfBirth": "01/01/1970",
      "occupation": "TCH"
    },
    "contractDetails": {
        "startDate": "08/12/2022"
    }
}
```

In my application I had a Customer model which looked like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
public class Customer {
  @NotEmpty 
  private String dateOfBirth;

  @NotNull
  @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Z]{3}", message=INVALID_CODE)
  private String occupation;

  @Valid @NotNull private ContractDetails contractDetails;
}
```

Has now changed to:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
public class Customer {
  @Valid @NotNull private PersonalDetails personalDetails;
  @Valid @NotNull private ContractDetails contractDetails;
}


@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
public class PersonalDetails {
  @NotEmpty 
  private String dateOfBirth;

  @NotNull
  @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Z]{3}", message=INVALID_CODE)
  private String occupation;
}
```

Is there any way I can identify variables or classes with some type of versioning so one client might continue to use the old structure whislt anothe client might use the new structure? Without some means of identifying this the API could quickly accumulate a lot of duplicate code and it may be confusing for anyone to enhance/debug. Eventually I'd like to include some process for identifying versions that are no longer in use and depricate them.

Comment: Usually this is done using a version number in the path of the URL, then deploying your application multiple times. If your classes change content but keep the same FQCN, they cannot exist in the same runtime environment (=VM) anyways.

Comment: or also in the namespace so you'll get a class by version and you can have multiversion in same app.